# Удалить папку с root правами

Tags: java, android

Как удалить папку например /data/data/com.android.chrome/cache ,если на телефоне есть root права?

Comment: В каком смысле удалить? Програмно или вручную через приложение?

Comment: программно, через собственное созданное приложение, тоесть предоставить приложению root права и удалить папку

Comment: Дать приложению рут может только пользователь, само приложение их взять не может. Если есть рут-права, то удалять так же, как и любую другую обычную папку.

Answer (score 2):

[Получение «ROOT» прав для Android-приложения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application)

> "Все, что вам нужно сделать, это расширить class ExecuteAsRootBase и переопределить метод getCommandsToExecute, чтобы вернуть команды, которые вы хотите выполнить с правами root."

[Как программно удалить файлы на Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659704/how-do-i-delete-files-programmatically-on-android/24659789)

```
try{
        File file = new File("/data/data/com.android.chrome/cache");
        if(file.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete operation is failed."); 
        }
    }catch(Exception x){
        System.out.println("Error. File not found.");
    }
```